# Flutter, Dart How to convert time to yestarday if old time compare with current time

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter dart,
I am trying to get the message if old compared with current
for example
old time is 11:00 PM
and current 12:00 AM or 01:00AM

return message should be yesterday

or
old time is 04:00 AM
current time 12:00 AM or 01:00AM

return message it's yesterday

Comment: DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime(2022-08-24 11:00:00.000);

If(scheduledTime.compareTo(DateTime.now()).isNegative) {
 scheduledTime.add(Duration(hours: 24));
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) method [`isAfter(<DateTime>)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) or [`isBefore(<DateTime>)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html)

You can use them to compare the dates of your messages and return the right message.

```dart
msgOne.date.isBefore(msgTwo.date) ? return msgOne : return msgTwo;
```